# How to Align The Navbar dropdown with Navbar Nav in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please let me know how I can align the navbar dropdown with it's associated  nav?
[image]
As you can see from the picture I have a `class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us` and when ever I click on it the dropdown menu appears more toards the left side of the nav!

```
<li class="dropdown open">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Programs</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kids News</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Parents Login</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Take a Tour</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Is there any way to allign it with the corner of it's nav toggle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add to your css code a line like that:

```
.dropdown-menu{ top: ?; left:?}
```

replace the '?' with the height of your navbar and test it. to fit your spectatives

**EDIT:**

By defect, the nav menu is aligned to the corner of the nav parent. you need to check your code.

Comment: Thanks bimba, this is working ONLY on vertical setting I mean the 'top' property! As you said it is changing the top distance but the left property NOT Working! can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: Behseini, I'm having the same problem with only the vertical setting working. How did you get the left property to work??